# Apache 2.4.18 randomly giving 404 for existing files

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to get my head around why this would be happening. I've never had problems on this server around this, so I'm a bit baffled.

The server is nginx + Apache 2.4 reverse proxy. So nginx I have this proxy pass:

```
    location ~ \.cgi$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        gzip off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;

    }
```

Then for the domains in Apache config I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:8181>

    # other stuff here

    <Directory "/the/web/directory/*">
        Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The domain is enabled and running fine normally. However, when developing a site for someone I just came across a weird error.

Every now and then the page gives a 404:

[image]

..yet the rest of the time it works fine.  In this instance I was sending the exact same params to it (just re-submitting the form). I have checked to see if the problem is with AJAX request, but I get the same problem if I open the URL up in a tab and press reload a few times to test.

Nothing helpful comes up in Apache log file:

```
authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: https://x.co.uk/contact.html
```

I'm pretty confident the error is coming from the Apache end, as the response for the 404 is:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /cgi-bin/contact.cgi was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at x.co.uk Port 8181
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what this could be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm weird - scrap that. I gave it a reboot and it all works fine now! Very odd how no error messages were in the domains error log - nor the main Apache error log (in /var/log)